# Read input as nested list in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am new to python. 
I want to read the input from stdin as nested list.

**Stdin:**

```
student1 90
student2 85
student3 98
```

My list should be as follows:

```
student = [['student1',90],['student2',85],['student3',98]]
```

Is there any way I can read the input using list comprehension without needing any extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
mystr = 'student1 90\nstudent2 85\nstudent3 98'

[[i[0], int(i[1])] for i in (k.split() for k in mystr.split('\n'))]

# [['student1', 90], ['student2', 85], ['student3', 98]]
```

Comment: You have to change second element in the list to integer. Nice solution beside this.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = []
while some_condition:
  read = input()
  my_list.append(read.split())
  my_list[-1][1] = int(my_list[-1][1])
```

Now let's break it down:

1. Create an empty list,
2. Keep on reading from stdin (you get str here)
3. add read element to your list by splitting it (it will create a new list).
4. Turn second element of last inserted item to integer.

**EDIT**
That's what it runs like:

```
In [1]: my_list = []
   ...: while True:
   ...:   read = input()
   ...:   my_list.append(read.split())
   ...:   my_list[-1][1] = int(my_list[-1][1])
   ...:   print(my_list)
   ...:   
student 1
[['student', 1]]
student 2
[['student', 1], ['student', 2]]
student 3
[['student', 1], ['student', 2], ['student', 3]]
```